# Make search result display 1 Company or 2 Companies

Tags: search

I am wondering if this could be done if i want something like this. Look at my code please.

Here the code goes:

```
<?php _e('Search result for','NCC'); ?> 
<?php /* Search Count */ 
    $allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
    $key = wp_specialchars($s, 1); 
    $count = $allsearch->post_count; 
    _e(''); 
    _e('"<span>'); 
    echo $key; 
    _e('</span>"'); 
    _e('<span class="resultsFound">( We found '); echo $count . ' '; _e('companies )</span>'); 
    wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

The outcome of this code will be:

```
( We found 1 companies )
```

Is it possible to make it work like the result saying "company" when there is 0 or 1 result found and saying "companies" when there are more 2 or more results found when we using the wp search box?

Example:

```
(1 company found) or (2 companies found)
```

Any suggestion? Is it possible with wordpress?

Comment: I'm sure someone will look at your code if it is properly formatted. Your complete code section is in one looooonnnnggg line, making it unreadable. Please file an [edit] and correct your code formatting

Comment: Hi Pieter Goosen, thanks for advises! But, how should i use this code? I am a newbie in php coding. Need more detailed instruction. Appreciate it! :)

Comment: I have formatted your code to make it readable. Remember in future, if your posts aren't properly formatted or your code is unreadable, others tend to just skip and ignore your question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$found_posts` holds the amount of posts found by a certain query. You can use this logic to display your links

Example:

```
if ( $allsearch->found_posts <= 1 ) {
    //Dispaly company
} else {
    // Disply companies
}
```

Just a note on grammar, it should be `0 companies` `1 company` and `x amount of companies` after that

### **EDIT**

From the edit I have done to your question, I have the following: To be honest, your code is a bit of a mess, but nothing that cannot be fixed though :-). Lets take a quick run down

- `showposts` is depreciated in favor of `posts_per_page`
- [`wp_specialchars`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_specialchars) has been depreciated since v2.8.0. You should be using [`esc_html`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html). But to be honest, I don't know if it is appropriate here.
- You should not localize HTML tags, just literal text should be localized. Exclude HTML tags from strings to be localized and make use of placeholders
- `wp_reset_query()` should be used with `query_posts` which you should never ever use. You should be using `wp_reset_postdata()` with `WP_Query`. In this case it is not necessary as you are not setting up postdata or changing the global `$post` variable
- I'm not very sure if you really need to localize the value of `$key`

As already stated in the other answer, you can make use of `_n()` to localize strings with single and plural meaning. As I have already stated, the correct grammar and use is

- `0 companies` `1 company` and `x amount of companies`

Your issue is in this line

```
_e('<span class="resultsFound">( We found '); echo $count . ' '; _e('companies )</span>');
```

We can rewrite it to something like this

```
$text  = '<span class="resultsFound">';
$text .= sprintf( _n( 'We found %d company', 'We found %d companies', $count ), $count );
$text .= '</span>'; 
echo $text;
```

If you really need to display `0 company`, you can use

```
$text  = '<span class="resultsFound">';
if ( $allsearch->found_posts <= 1 ) {
    $text .= sprintf(__( 'We found %d company' ), $count );
} else {
    $text .= sprintf(__( 'We found %d companies' ), $count );
}       
$text .= '</span>'; 
echo $text;
```

or

```
$text  = '<span class="resultsFound">';
if ( $allsearch->post_count <= 1 ) {
    $text .= sprintf(__( 'We found %d company' ), $count );
} else {
    $text .= sprintf(__( 'We found %d companies' ), $count );
}       
$text .= '</span>'; 
echo $text;
```

Comment: Please see my update. This should get you going

Comment: Hi Pieter Goosen, thanks for your explanation and a clear instruction! I follow the steps and now it works. I will make every question readable in future. Again, thanks for your help! I appreciate it. :)

Comment: No problem, my pleasure. Glad you got this solved. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `_n` function instead of `_e`.

Read this: [`_n`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n)